# FCKeditor having problem with url rewriting in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fckeditor

I have used FCKeditor in my project. It worked fine before i add url rewriting in my project.
Now i can not upload images from my fckeditor properly.

I am using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter for url rewriting in asp.net.

Can any one help me to get out of this kind of problem?

Comment: It is just a thought but maybe you can use CKEditor, because FCKeditor is kind of obsolete.

Comment: Now, it's to late to change it. any other suggestion.

Comment: Didn't even know people still used FailCKEditor or CKEditor, thought everyone was using TinyMCE now.

Comment: I don't think what made you write this comment but it is obvious that you never used ckeditor. What if someone wants to use a simple file browser integrated to it? For TinyMCE you have to buy one but for CKEditor you already have one (CKFinder).

Comment: @edem - Even tho you have to buy CKEditor. So your argument cancels itself out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the ISAPI rewrite rules are affecting where FCKEditor accesses the necessary html files causing a permanent 404.

Add a rule to exclude the images folder from being rewritten and you should be good to go.

Take a look here for some information about setting rules: http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/using

Comment: I removed all my rule for images and css and add rule which is in this post and it's done what i want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have web.config file? If yes, try these settings in that file

```
<appsettings>
<add key="FCKeditor:UserFilesPath" value="~/UserFilesUpload" /> 
</appsettings>
```